# Issues creating a CD based release on Github (WPF .NET 5.0)

Tags: continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm trying to put together a CI / CD pipeline for GitHub and strugglign with attaching my build artifact to the release. Here's my ci.yml

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  Build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      BuildPath: ${{ github.workspace }}\BuildTesting\bin\Release\net5.0-windows


    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Setup .NET SDK
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.8.1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 5.0.x

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore
        
      - name: Upload a Build Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2.2.4
        with:
          name: thingy
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}\BuildTesting\bin\Release\net5.0-windows

          retention-days: 1
```

That runs well and I get a release artifact:
[image]

I was under the impression I'd be able to download that existing artifact but I couldn't get my head around why `actions/download-artifact` isn't downloading anything. So I found another article and in their cd step they were re-building, so I figured that in doing that at least I'd have a fresh build in the cd workflow to pull from. So I create a release triggered on tag push events. I can't use most zip utilities becuase they don't run on windows. I have to user windows-latest as the target framework for WPF desktop applications has to be net5.0-windows and using ubuntu-latest it fails. I tried `papeloto/action-zip@v1` and in one case I managed to get a zip file which then attached to the release successfully but was only 22 bytes, so empty once I downloaded it. Here's my cd.yml:

```
name: CD

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - '*'

jobs:
  Release:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    env:
      BuildPath: ${{ github.workspace }}\BuildTesting\bin\Release\net5.0-windows
      ZipName: TheThing.zip

    steps:
      # Build the solution
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        
      - name: Setup .NET SDK
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1.8.1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 5.0.x

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

      - name: Zip the release
        uses: << What should I use to zip ${{ env.BuildPath }} ? >>
        

      # Create a Release on the GitHub project
      - name: Create release
        id: create_release
        uses: actions/create-release@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # This token is provided by Actions, you do not need to create your own token
        with:
          tag_name: ${{ github.ref }}
          release_name:  ${{ github.ref }}
          draft: false
          prerelease: false

      # Upload the Build Artifact to the Release
      - name: Update release asset
        id: upload-release-asset
        uses: actions/upload-release-asset@v1
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ steps.create_release.outputs.upload_url }}  # This pulls from the CREATE RELEASE step above, referencing it's ID to get its outputs object, which include a `upload_url`. See this blog post for more info: https://jasonet.co/posts/new-features-of-github-actions/#passing-data-to-future-steps 
          asset_path: .\${{ env.ZipName }}
          asset_name: ${{ env.ZipName }}
          asset_content_type: application/zip
```

Can anyone please recommend a GitHub action for zipping a folder that will work for windows-latest ... or another approach?
Long term I want to go with semantic versioning but GitVersion overwhelmed me last time I tried, granted I'd never working with yml builds before. I'd like to keep this as simple as possible as I'm starting to grok the basics of what's going on and once I get past this I'll start looking into GitVersion.

I'm using a test repository located [here](https://github.com/steveski/BuildTesting) so you can see the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You may use PowerShell to zip your artifacts using 7Zip. Please check my repository in [GitHub](https://github.com/joymon/dotnet-watcher). That compile a WPF app, compress the artifacts, create a prerelease and upload files under that release.